# Connecting to web server using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm currently trying to connect to a web server using Visual Studio 2010 (as I need to code several pages using ASP.NET) and have no idea how to. I've managed to connect to the SQL database to set up the tables but cannot actually see the files on the web server (under the Visual Studio 2010 IDE) so that I can work with both asp files on the web server and database.

So far I've managed to connect to the web server using WinSCP (following the instructions [**here**](http://co-web.lboro.ac.uk/notes/config.htm) via a VPN) but I cannot seem to connect to the same web server under Visual Studio 2010.

The server owner has provided information [**here**](http://co-web.lboro.ac.uk/notes/config.htm) but none of it seems to make any sense to me. Can anyone suggest some good tutorials? I'd really appreciate a helping hand.

Comment: Why do you want to connect to the webserver using VS? Wouldn't it be better to develop the app locally and deploy to the server later?

Comment: Develop locally, hopefully you can deploy to a development server, and once everything is working, then you publish to live server. Modifying files directly on the live server = recipe for disaster.